# MongoDB Grouping Array Elements of already grouped documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, grouping

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm trying to do grouping of array elements in documents which are already grouped (and I want to keep the first grouping).

I have the following basic documents:

```
{
  user: "user_a",
  upload_folder: "folder_x",
  created_at: "2018-08-30 00:00:00",
  volume: 25678
},
{
  user: "user_a",
  upload_folder: "folder_x",
  created_at: "2018-08-29 00:00:00",
  volume: 567
},
{
  user: "user_b",
  upload_folder: "folder_a",
  created_at: "2018-08-30 00:00:00",
  volume: 25678
}
```

I want to get a result first grouped by dates (to get number and volume of all transfers per day) and then grouped by user and folder to get information about numer of transfers per user and volume per user.

The final result should look like this:

```
[
 _id: {month:08, day:30, year: 2018},
 totalVolume: 51356,
 totalTransfers: 1,
 users: [
  {
   name:user_a,
   transfersPerUser:1,
   volumePerUser:25678,
   destinations:[
     folder: "folder_x",
     transfersPerDestination: 1,
     volumePerDestination: 25678
   ]
  }
 ]
]
```

The first question for me is: Does it make sense to do this in one query or am I on the wrong course?

What I already have is the grouping per date and the sums of volume and transfers per day.
But I do not know how to do the second grouping, as now each single transfer per user is in an array.

I tried to do a $unwire for the array and to group each unwired entry. But how can I add the result to the origin document grouped by the date?

Get results in range of date:

```
$match: {
        creationDate: {
            $gte: ISODate('2018-08-01 00:00:00'),
            $lte: ISODate('2018-08-31 00:00:00')
        }
}
```

Group results by date

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            month: {
                $month: "$created_at"
            },
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth: "$created_at"
            },
            year: {
                $year: "$created_at"
            },
        },
        uploads: {
            $push: {
                "user": "$user",
                "upload_folder": "$upload_folder",
                "volume": "$volume"
            }
        },
        volumPerDay: {
            $sum: "$volume"
        },
        transfersPerDay: {
            $sum: 1
        }
}
```

How can I proceed? Using `$unwind` and then?

```
$unwind { path: "$user"}
```

Thank you very much for any help.